# Eclipse custom message unresolved inclusion

Tags: catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,
I know that might be a common question, but all the solutions I have found did not work.  I can import my project (around 35 packages) and all the inclusions work perfectly. However, when comes to the inclusion of messages it shows an error and says that the inclusion of the message header is unresolved even if the message is defined in the same package where it is used. Moreover, it builds the project without any problem.
Of course I followed the steps in the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Creating_the_Eclipse_project_files%3C/p%3E) to set up  Eclipse with ROS and catkin.
Any clues on what it can be?

Thank you very much

Andrea

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208186/eclipse-custom-message-unresolved-inclusion/) by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was a compiling problem. There were some packages with errors and the messages were not generated. To verify it I looked in the devel/include folder of the workspace.

Thank you very much anyway
Andrea

---

Originally posted by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) with karma: 385 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0